# why the below merge sort code doesnt work?

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, merge

What should be changed in the below code? It shows the following error

> ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/bot/funcs.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
>
> Error in `/home/bot/dcb7b4b8f54571a4467c2113b7856878': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000c350b0

```
      #include <iostream>

      using namespace std;

      int merge(int *left,int nl,int *right,int nr,int *a)
      {

         int i=0,j=0,k=0;
         while(i<nl && j<nr)
         {
            if(left[i]<right[j])
            {
             a[k]=left[i];
             i++;
            }
            else
            {
             a[k]=right[j];
             j++;
             }
            k++;
           }
        while(i<nl)
        {
         a[k]=left[i];
          i++;
        }
       while(j<nr)
       {
         a[k]=right[j];
         j++;
       }
 }
 int mergesort(int *a,int n)
{

      if(n<2) return 0;
      int mid=n/2;
      int *left=new int[mid];
      int *right=new int[n-mid];

    for(int i=0;i<=mid-1;i++)
    {
      left[i]=a[i];
     }
     for(int i=mid;i<=n-1;i++)
     {
       right[i]=a[i];
     }
      mergesort(left,mid);
      mergesort(right,n-mid);
      merge(left,mid,right,n-mid,a);
     delete[]left;
     delete[]right;
    }

   int main() {
       //code
      int a[]={10,7,8,9,4,2,3,6,5,1};
      int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
      mergesort(a,n);
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
       cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
      }
      return 0;
       }
```

Comment: why you do not use `std::vector` instead of raw pointer?

Comment: i have little knowledge of what std::vector does.so can u plz tell changes can i make in d above basic code?

Comment: @sneha -  I posted an answer with only the changes needed to fix your basic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes noted in comments, seems to be working now. A one time allocation of a temp array either in main or in a helper function would be faster. Using mutually recursive functions (one merges AtoA, the other merges AtoTemp, they call each other), eliminates having to copy data. I can post an example later if wanted. Bottom up merge sort would be slightly faster.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// fix return type to void
void merge(int *left,int nl,int *right,int nr,int *a)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<nl && j<nr)
    {
        if(left[i]<right[j])
        {
            a[k]=left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            a[k]=right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<nl)
    {
        a[k]=left[i];
        i++;
        k++;                    // fix
    }
    while(j<nr)
    {
        a[k]=right[j];
        j++;
        k++;                    // fix
    }
}

// fix return type to void
void mergesort(int *a,int n)
{
    if(n<2) return;             // fix: change return type to void
    int mid=n/2;
    int *left=new int[mid];
    int *right=new int[n-mid];

    for(int i=0;i<=mid-1;i++)
    {
        left[i]=a[i];
    }
    for(int i=mid;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        right[i-mid]=a[i];      // fix
    }
    mergesort(left,mid);
    mergesort(right,n-mid);
    merge(left,mid,right,n-mid,a);
    delete[]left;
    delete[]right;
}

int main() {
    //code
    int a[]={10,7,8,9,4,2,3,6,5,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    mergesort(a,n);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout << endl;               // added this not needed
    return 0;
}
```

Cleanup, changed output to not use tabs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>              // for std::setw()

using namespace std;

void merge(int *left,int nl,int *right,int nr,int *a)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<nl && j<nr)
    {
        if(left[i]<right[j])
            a[k++]=left[i++];
        else
            a[k++]=right[j++];
    }
    while(i<nl)
        a[k++]=left[i++];
    while(j<nr)
        a[k++]=right[j++];
}

void mergesort(int *a,int n)
{
    if(n<2)
        return;
    int mid=n/2;
    int *left=new int[mid];
    int *right=new int[n-mid];

    for(int i=0;i<=mid-1;i++)
        left[i]=a[i];
    for(int i=mid;i<=n-1;i++)
        right[i-mid]=a[i];
    mergesort(left,mid);
    mergesort(right,n-mid);
    merge(left,mid,right,n-mid,a);
    delete[]left;
    delete[]right;
}

int main() {
    int a[]={10,7,8,9,4,2,3,6,5,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    mergesort(a,n);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout<<setw(2)<<a[i]<<" ";  // 2 digit field output
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damn, you've beaten me! :-) I was also working on it, and I had also found the missing `k++` in `merge()`, but I was still looking for the other bug. Now that I see your solution it looks obvious... Well done!

Comment: @FabioTurati - right[i-mid] was the other fix. Without that fix, the heap would be corrupted, but I'm wondering if the program would otherwise appear to work.

Comment: My first attempt to fix the program was to create `left` and `right` with a size of `n`, that is, to overprovision them. It was more a guess than a well-thought idea, but the program did indeed stop crashing, as I expected. But the output was garbage; no, it didn't appear to work. So I started debugging it and I had found the missing `k++` but I hadn't paid enough attention to the other line. Then I saw there was an answer and I couldn't resist the temptation to check it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::vector` instead of raw pointer:

```
typedef std::vector<int> ivector;

void merge( const ivector &l, const ivector &r, ivector &to )
{
     ivector_const::iterator il = l.begin();
     ivector_const::iterator ir = r.begin();
     ivector::iterator ito = to.begin();

     while( true ) {
         if( il == l.end() ) {
              if( ir == r.end() ) 
                  return;
              *ito++ = *ir++;
         } else {
              if( ir == r.end() || *il < *ir )
                  *ito++ = *il++;
              else
                  *ito++ = *ir++;
         }
    }
}

void mergesort( ivector &v )
{
      if(v.size()<2) return;
      ivector::iterator imid = v.begin() + v.size() / 2;
      ivector left( v.begin(), imid );
      ivector right( imid, v.end() );

      mergesort(left);
      mergesort(right);
      merge( left, right, v );
}

int main() {
    //code
    ivector a ={10,7,8,9,4,2,3,6,5,1};
    mergesort(a);
    for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
       cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I did not validate your algorithm just rewrote it with `std::vector` instead of raw pointer. You can notice how simpler your function become when you use proper data type.

Comment: can there be any other way to do without using std::vector?

Comment: @sneha yes, run debugger and go through your long code and try to understand what is wrong there.